# how to check if a row is checked and a specific cell is empty using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Basically when a user clicks submit in my MVC 3 application.
I want to use jquery to check if any of the rows selected (selected via checkboxes) have any value in a particular cell in that row.
and is not display an alert mgs or validation error.

Rough code attempt:

```
$("#MultiSubBtn").click(function () {
        if ((':checkbox').is(':checked') && ('td').find("attBtn").isempty())
            alert("there is a cert missing");
    });
```

In the above MultiSubBtn is the id on my Submit btn.
and the cell I am trying to query id a

Still learning when it comes to jquery , here is the full html page.
I removed some elements to reduce page size.

```
 <div id="tabs-1" style="position:relative; left:-12%;">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("SentMultipleCalsToCustomer", "CalibrationViewer", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        @* This is the table that contains a single page of the paginated table of recent calibrations *@
     <table id="all-calibrations" class="grid tracker-grid" style="width:77%">
        <colgroup>
            <col class ="" style="width:11%">
            <col class="workno-data" style="width:13%">
            <col class="equipmentId-data" style="width:8%">
            <col class="equipmentDesc-data" style="width:12%">
        </colgroup>

    <thead>
        <tr>
        @* ADDED 20/08/2014 *@
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Work<br />No.</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            @* the customer column is only shown for LTS users since customer only see 1 customers data *@
            @if (this.User.IsInRole("LTS User Passive"))
            {
                <th style="width:15%;">Customer</th>
            }
            <th style="text-align: center; width:15%;">Cert</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
         @* iterate through each calibration shown on this page *@
         @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count(); index++)
         {
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).CustomerName)
            <tr>

            @* The work number is a link to the calibration the work no. represents *@
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectecals" value="@Model.ElementAt(index).Id"/></td>

            <td>@Html.ActionLink("WN–" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).Id), "Index", "CalibrationViewer", new { id = Model.ElementAt(index).Id }, null)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).EquipmentID)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).EquipmentDescription)</td>
            @* once again only the lts user sees the customer column data *@
            @if (this.User.IsInRole("LTS User Passive"))
            {
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).CustomerName)</td>
            }

          @*   if the calibration has an attachment display the name of the file,
             else display the Upload button*@

             @if (Model.ElementAt(index).CertName != null)
             {
                 <td style="background-color:#33CC00; color:#fff;">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).CertName)</td>
             }
             else
             {     // style="background-color:#5C9CCC"  // ----- to allow for btn           
                <td id ="attBtn" class="file-uploader-attachment-Class"></td>
             }

         </tr>  

             <script type="text/javascript">
                 var CUST_NAME = '@Model.ElementAt(index).CustomerName'; 
            </script>
         }
    </tbody>  
</table>            

         if (Model.Count() != 0)
         {
        <div id="calibrationViewer-rightColumn" style="display:inline-block; position:absolute; top:8.5%; left:80%; width:20%">
               @{Html.RenderPartial("StatusForm", InstrumentTracker.Common.Enums.Status.Finished_Calibration);}   

               <input type="submit" style="width:100%;" class="styledbutton" id="MultiSubBtn" value="Submit" />
               <input type="hidden" name="customer" value="@ViewBag.CustomerName" />  
               <br /> <br />
    <button class="styledbutton" style="width:100%;" onclick="window.location.href='/Tracker/Index'">Return to Main Tracker Page</button>
        </div>
         }
    } @*end using form tag*@

</div>​
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#MultiSubBtn").click(function () {
        if ((':checkbox').is(':checked') &&    ('td').find("attBtn").isempty())
            alert("there is a cert missing");
    });



    function handleCheckbox() {
        if ($(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').removeClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");

            createUploader($(this));

            $(this).find('.qq-upload-list').css("margin", "0px")

        }

        else {
            $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').addClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
            $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').html($('#myHTML2').html());
        }
    }

    $('tr').each(handleCheckbox);
    $('tr').on('click', handleCheckbox);


        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle/jsbin example for the same

Comment: Can you please see your HTML. We need to know how to traverse the DOM in your page from the button to the cell and checkbox

Comment: In your `if` statement in the first code block above, you've forgotten the `$` before `(':checkbox')`. Is that a typo? If not, that may be your only problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the only problem.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your intent. Why are you trying to find("attBtn")? fyi, you are using the same id on every row. Seems like you'd want to a) query the dom to find which rows contain the checkmark and b) iterate over those results to find in which of those rows the particular field is empty.

Comment: Why not use a [foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` attribute and let unobtrusive validation handle all this for you? And you should be using `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[index].CustomerName)` in the loop so your controls are correctly named and you avoid invalid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated your problem as "if any of the rows selected (selected via checkboxes) have any value in a particular cell in that row"

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdrans/buyb56e7/)

This is a somewhat crude example, but see if this helps you any. It's a static table with input fields. If you enter data into column C and click the associated checkbox it finds the cell and changes the text color. If the cell is empty it changes the background color. Just to illustrate finding the cell and acting on its contents.

There are many ways (better ways than this no doubt) to do stuff like this, but the flow should be the same.

1) Find the checkboxes that are checked. `var ch = $(":checked");`

2) Iterate over collection of elements returned from your search `ch.each(function () {}`

a) determine what row you are currently looking at `parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');`(perhaps optional but that's how I do it)

b) find the cell in that row `parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');`and determine if it is "empty" based on your own criteria.

Personally, I don't hesitate to add classes data- elements or whatever is going to help me retrieve what I need later, so you'll note I added a class to that column's TD's as a convenience.

**JQUERY**

```
$(".checkbox").on("click", function () {
var ch = $(":checked");
var parentRow;
var cellInQuestion;
ch.each(function () {
    parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    cellInQuestion = $(parentRow).find(".C");
    if (cellInQuestion.val() === "") {
        cellInQuestion.css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        cellInQuestion.css("color", "green");
    }
});
```

});

**HTML**

`<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th style="color:green;">C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="parentrow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="C" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="parentrow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="C" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="parentrow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="C" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="width:40px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`

Comment: Thanks for the highly detailed answer. Will put it into use.